# ViewController does not display the View

Tags: swift, uiview

When adding a UILabel to my ViewController, it displays fine, but as soon as I use a seperate UIView, the controller displays nothing. The ViewController is pushed from a TableViewController.didSelectRowAt

The ViewController is called in the didSelectRowAt

```swift
let labelViewController = TempViewController()                
navigationController?.pushViewController(labelViewController, animated: true)
```

Scenario 1: Only ViewController - Displays a blue screen with the text in the y-center of the screen as expected

```swift
class TempViewController: UIViewController {
    var tempView: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Please enter your email address"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        navigationItem.title = "Temp"
        edgesForExtendedLayout = []

        view.addSubview(tempView)
        tempView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tempView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tempView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tempView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

Scenario 2: ViewController and View - Displays a red screen with no text and no blue

```swift
class TempViewController: UIViewController {

    var tempView = TempView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        navigationItem.title = "Temp"
        edgesForExtendedLayout = []

        view.addSubview(tempView)
        tempView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tempView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tempView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tempView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

```swift
class TempView: UIView {
    var tempView: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Please enter your email address"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return label
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setView()
    }

    private func setView() {
        addSubviews()
        setLayout()
    }

    private func addSubviews() {
        addSubview(tempView)
    }

    private func setLayout() {
                tempView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
                tempView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
                tempView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
                tempView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

I would expect both scenarios to produce the same result? But Scenario 2 does not display the view?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view isn't showing because it is over constrained.

You need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` for `tempView` as well in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
view.addSubview(tempView)
tempView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tempView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
tempView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
tempView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
tempView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, stupid mistake. Yes tempView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false in ViewController.viewDidLoad()